# Join fetch fails on fetching 3rd level relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have three entities: `Person`, `Country` and `CountryTranslation`.
`Person` is related to one `Country` and `Country` have many `CountryTranslations`.

I want my query to fetch both `Country` and `CountryTranslations` when it fetches a `Person` in order to avoid multiple queries.

To bring the `Country` along with `Person` I do:

```
List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT person from Person person " +
                             "left join fetch person.country")
                .getResultList()
```

This works fine, I see on hibernate it is fetching nicely and no extra queries are executed to bring `Country`, but to bring `CountryTranslations` it still execute extra queries. Then I tried:

```
List<Person> persons = (List<Person>) entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT person from Person person " +
                             "left join fetch person.country " +
                             "left join fetch person.country.translations")
                .getResultList()
```

And I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

What is the right way to do this fetching?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try removing the "fetch" keyword - thus way Hibernate will not include the association in the Select clause; You can explore the details in https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/query-specified-join-fetching-but-the-owner-of-the-fetched-association-was-not-present-in-the-select-list/258

Comment: Try to change to `SELECT person from Person person left join fetch person.country country left join fetch country.translations"`

Comment: @HenriqueMentz this did the trick. Giving an alias to it. Do you know if there's a reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correct this giving an alias for each relationship.

```
SELECT person 
FROM  person person 
LEFT JOIN FETCH person.country country 
LEFT JOIN FETCH country.translations
```

It's a framework's "limitation": When you use linked fetchs you should to give an alias for each relationship!

This behavior can also be explained because will be difficult to understand what these linked fetches really mean: Does the framework will fetch each relationship or only the last one? It's more simple to just tell to the framework what fetch relationship you want.